# Can't see multiple layers when adding a WMS

Tags: wms, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.8.2.

I have a WMS (https://openwms.statkart.no/skwms1/wms.topo4.graatone?) that I want to add, and in Arcgis it lists several layers (33 total) in the table of contents. When I add it in QGIS, only one is showing, it doesnt matter if I select all or only the parent layer in the WMS. Is there some boxes that needs to be ticked ahead of the operation?[image: topo-wms]

[image: result]

Comment: I guess that you must add layers one by one. WMS works so that server combines the layers into one image on the server side if client requests a list of layers `&LAYERS=layer_1,layer_2,layer_3`.

Comment: Yes, add them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct and expected behaviour, if you select several layers at the same time and add them to QGIS it will make one request for all of the selected layers and add them as a single QGIS layer. If you need to have the ability to turn individual layers on and off in QGIS then you must add the layers one at a time, this will make QGIS make several separate requests for the layers.